# Finding all possible Jordan Normal Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I need help with finding all Jordan Normal Forms with following infos: $F$ is an  endomorphism of $V$, $\:\dim(V) = 8$, $\:\operatorname{rank}(F) = 5$, $\:\operatorname{rank}(F^2) = 4$, $\:\operatorname{rank}(F^3) = 3$, $\dim \ker(F-\operatorname{id}) = 2$, $\:\dim \ker(F-\operatorname{id})^2 = 3$. All we learned in class is finding Jordan Normal Forms with characteristic and minimal polynomials.

Comment: Please format your question so that it is readable. See the tutorial on mathematical formatting [given here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce the following notations for solving this problem: $m_k$=dimension of (F-aI)^k where I is the Identity matrix and "a" is an eigen value of F. Also let $b_k$=Number of k blocks (k by k) for an eigen value "a".

For the eigen value "0" we observe the following from the given data. Since rank(F)=5 we have nullity(F)=3 and hence "0" has geometric multiplicity 3. Also we have $m_0$=0 (always for any eigen value), $m_1$=3; $m_2$=4 and $m_3$=5. Hence $b_1$=number of one blocks for eigen value "0" = 2$m_1$-$m_2$-$m_0$=6-4-0=2.
$b_2$=2$m_2$-$m_3$-$m_1$=8-5-3=0.
So eigen value "0" has no 2 blocks but since its gm is 3 it must have a 3 or higher block.
Repeating the calculations for eigen value "1" we conclude that it has one 1 block and at least one higher block.
Putting all together we have Eigen value "0" repeated 5 times (AM=5) with two 1 blocks and one 3 block and Eigen value "1" with AM=3 with one 1 block and one 2 block and hence the JNF is uniquely determined by the given data as [0,0,(0,0,0),1,(1,1)].

Comment: @Michael Maier !! Five days have passed after an answer was given to your question. Either you must say the answer is wrong or if you don't follow the arguments in the answer you must further seek clarification on the answer. After getting an answer leaving it at that doesn't help. Please consider this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for the late response. I have the following questions: 1)could you please explain where did read out the eigenvalues "o" and "1"? 2) where did you read out the AM of "0" =5 and AM of "1" = 3?

Comment: Nullity F=3 means the Eigen value 0 is repeated at least 3 times. Nullity of (F-I)=2 means Eigen value 1 is repeated at least twice. These are Geometric multiplicities. The Arithmetic multiplicity is arrived at by working out the number of blocks which is given in the solution.

Comment: why does $m_0$ = 0 for any EV?

Comment: Put k=0 in the definition of m_k. Note that (F-aI)^0 =I and the nullity of the identity matrix is 0.